Verilog: Comparing signed value vs. unsigned value yields unexpected result
In Verilog, I want to compare signed and unsigned values.  The following code (val > valS) gave me unexpected result. In the code below, unsigned variable (val) should be interpreted as "12", while signed variable (valS06) should be interpreted as -4. So, I expect (val > valS) to be true, but the simulation result is (val < valS).   Why the result is as such?
  logic [3:0] val;
  logic signed [5:0] valS06;

  val=4'b1100; 
  valS06 = 6'b111100; 
  
  $display("val %04b | valS06 %b", val, valS06);

  if(val>valS06 )    // <== should hit here
    $display("val > valS");
  else if(val==valS06)
    $display("val == valS");
  else
    $display("val < valS"); // <= actually hit here --- why??

Log:
val 1100 | valS06 111100
val 12   | valS06  -4
val < valS


The problem is that you are comparing two things that are not alike.
From IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 11.4.4 Relational operators:

When one or both operands of a relational expression are unsigned, the
expression shall be interpreted as a comparison between unsigned
values.

You can cast the unsigned val to signed using $signed.
Also, the bit widths differ.  You can explicitly pad the 4-bit value with zeroes to make their widths match:
  if ($signed({2'b00, val}) > valS06)
    $display("val > valS");
  else if ($signed({2'b00, val}) == valS06)
    $display("val == valS");
  else
    $display("val < valS");

This results in:
val > valS

